# Can't select python3.10 interpreter in PyCharm in Ubuntu23.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm, interpreter, python-3.10

Ubuntu23.04 has python3.11 as a default ver. I needed python3.10, but deadsnakes doesn't have the release file for Ubuntu23.04, and clear installation with `sudo apt install python3.10` has no installation candidates. So, i've decided to [compile](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/compile-install-python-3-10-ubuntu/) the python by myself.

After compiling python3.10 from source it has been installed in usr/bin/local. I've added this path to :**PATH** var and also added python3.10, located in usr/bin/local, to the system interpreter alternatives (I din't change default python, as long as it's critical for some Ubuntu23.04 tools, like `apt`).

After all of this manipulations i can call the interpreter with `python3.10 -V` as example.

But, when i'm trying to select the interpreter in PyCharm, i select the path to freshly created venv, but, PyCharm just drops the process. It's hard to explain, so, there is the screenshots.

[image]
Here^ i'm selecting the interpreter in freshly created venv with installed dependencies.

But when i try to add the interpreter, nothing happens and selected interpreter even doesn't appear in the interpreters list...
[image]

But, i can run the project via using command line (with pre-activated venv ofc) with `venv/bin/python3.10 main.py` and it works.

What have i done wrong and how can i use python3.10 in Ubuntu23.04 seamlessly, alongside with python3.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after contacting with *IntelliJ* support team.
They found out that my selected interpreter path and path from IDE logs were different. I think, that the problem was caused by kinda invalid renaming the folder.

So, the [main idea is here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html). You should restore default IDE settings, by `File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings`. That solved the problem for me. Thanks to *IntelliJ* support team.